# Details of socket using socket ID

Tags: java, c, sockets

This question may sound basic one . Are there any functions in c or Java where I can get the socket details like , port , address , buffer size using only socket identifier ?

Comment: Well, yes, there are. Two things you might want to consider: First, look for answers for one language at a time. Second, this is easy to google - what did you try before posting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minimal information available with me is posted below.

I don't know much of Java. But as far as 'C' is concerned, you can use the [getsockopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockopt) function to get the buffer sizes (send buffer and recv buffer) of the socket.

It appears [getsockname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) helps you in getting the ip & port to which the socket is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

In c in the function accept:

```
csock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&csin, &recsize);
```

- sock is the socket server(int)
- csock is the socket client (int)
- recsize is the size
- csin is a struct with client's details

  - csin.sin_addr is the client's address
  - csin.sin_port is the client's port

From a socket ID try this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

f()
{
   int s;
   struct sockaddr_in sa;
   int sa_len;
   .
   .
   .
      /* We must put the length in a variable.              */
   sa_len = sizeof(sa);
      /* Ask getsockname to fill in this socket's local     */
      /* address.                                           */
   if (getsockname(s, &sa, &sa_len) == -1) {
      perror("getsockname() failed");
      return -1;
   }

  /* Print it. The IP address is often zero beacuase    */
  /* sockets are seldom bound to a specific local       */
  /* interface.                                         */
   printf("Local IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sa.sin_add r));
   printf("Local port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(sa.sin_port));
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - this can only be used to get details about a socket when you accept it, not at any point later, just having its fd.